# Set a button in the center of tableview cell programatically

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have programatically made a button inside a tableview cell. I set the x and y of the button in the center of width and height of the cell. The problem is,  it would be in the center in bigger iPhone (Xs max and Xr), but it wont in the smaller iPhone such as SE. I don't understand why when I tell the center of the cell, it would be different in different iPhone. 
for example, the cell that has this button inside it called "EditCell"

```
let EditBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: EditCell.frame.width/2, y: EditCell.frame.height/2, width: 60, height: 60))
```

It will be made in a function and it is called in the `viewDidLoad`
could anyone help me about it?

Comment: Use constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let editBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
editBtn.center = EditCell.contentView.center
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but It has still problem with smaller iPhone (SE)

Answer (score 2):

You can try either

```
var editBtn = UIButton(type:.system)
editBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ 
    editBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerXAnchor),
    editBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor) 
])
```

or

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  editBtn.center = self.contentView.center
}
```

your code suggests that you add it inside `cellForRowAt` , so don't do this and instead add it inside the cell custom class init method if it's a programmatic cell and inside `awakeFormNib` if it's xib/prototype cell